# Inflate balloon when item is selected

Tags: android, dictionary, inflate, popup-balloons

I have a map activity that has many pins of map, and when I click a pin, a custom balloon opens, showing some information about that pin. Also, I have a search bar, where if you type the name of a knob, the info appears there, but I want it to go to that searched pin.
**Example:** *on the map you have different vegetables pins, and when you search carrot, the search list will show the element carrot, and when you click on it, the balloon for the carrot pin will inflate.* So, my **question** is : is there some sort of **OnTap**() void method ? I know, that **OnTap**(int index) returns a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create your own itemized overlay, and override the onTap method, and in your main class, make an instance of the itemized overlay, and call overlay.onTap(point)

Sample code:

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay<Item> extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> m_overlays;
    private MapView mapView;
    final MapController mc;

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker), mapView);
        m_overlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        mc = mapView.getController();
        populate();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        m_overlays.add(overlay);
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();
    }

    public ArrayList<OverlayItem> getOverlays() {
        return m_overlays;
    }

    public final boolean onTap(int index) {
        GeoPoint point;
        point = createItem(index).getPoint();
        mc.animateTo(point);    
        return true;
    }

    ...
}
```

In the main class

```
public class Main extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    private MyItemizedOverlay overlay;
private Drawable pin;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        doAction();
    }

    private void doAction() {
    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        pin = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);

        overlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(pin, mapView);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(7*1E6),(int)(42*1E6));
        overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "title", "text");

    overlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    mapOverlays.add(overlay);

        //we tap the point here
        overlay.onTap(0);
    }
}
```